# Two Columns, full height, responsive layout. Which framework to use?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I'd like to build a site with a two column full height (100% of the vieport) layout. Left column should contain a fixed height navigation and a specific background. Right column should contain a different background and the main content.

I toyed around with both Bootstrap and Foundation but both seem to make this combination of backgrounds/columns really hard to set up. I found a few solutions for that with jQuery but imho this would introduce another layer of possible confusion for something that should not be hard to implement in the first place.

Before I go and just roll my own css: Is there an easy, no JS way of archiving that look in either Bootstrap, Foundation or any of the other fully fledged framework? I'd like to be able to use columns, tabs, etc. in the main content so a framework would save me a lot of coding.

Thanks!

Comment: Setting up a basic layout isn't "a lot of coding", using a framework for something you've said you can do manually just isn't worth it for download speeds, maintainability etc. Just write it yourself

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS tables, easy to do. But trick needed for Chrome.

Example:
CSS:

```
/* important */
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#test {
  background: #ddd;
  display: block; /* important */
  margin: 0;
  /*  max-width: 400px; */
  min-height: 0; /* important */
  overflow: hidden; /* important */
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

#test .twoColumnLayout {
    display: table; /* important */
    height: 100%; /* important */
    margin-top: 20px;
    min-height: 10px; /* necessary for IE */
}

/* important, but only for IE, for others the row doesn't need to be present */
#test .twoColumnLayout .row {
    display: table-row; 
    height: 100%;
}

#test .twoColumnLayout .col {
    display: table-cell; /* important */
    height: 100%; /* important */
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%; /* for 2 columns */
}

#test .twoColumnLayout .col > .content {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 100%; /* important */
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;

    /* webkit fix!!! */
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* necessary for Chrome!!! */
}
```

And HTML for CSS above:

```
<section id="test">
  <div class="twoColumnLayout">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="content">
          Some content here, little bit shorter...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="content">
          Some content here, little bit longer. Some more content here, so it's even longer...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/slonisko/xmL5jjct/2/

Comment: Beautiful! How would i split the columns 70-30% instead of 50-50%? I tried and it is eluding me. Thanks.

Comment: You can add new classes to the columns (col-30, col-70). I made some update here https://jsfiddle.net/slonisko/xmL5jjct/7/ :)

Comment: Thanks, Radoslav.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Bootstrap and some other grid systems as well, imho they are only useful if you're going to code a more complex website. If you just need two columns, they're certainly overkill.

For example, this took me 2 minutes to setup, and seems to answer your request:
http://jsbin.com/abeciz/1/edit

Comment: Doesn't work if content is larger than the viewport and you need to scroll.